# decoding email subject in EXIM log

Tags: php, decode, exim

in my EXIM log I have this email subject

```
\316\225\317\200\316\271\316\262\316\265\316\262\316\261\316\257\317\211\317\203\316\267 \316\240\316\261\317\201\316\261\316\263\316\263\316\265\316\273\316\257\316\261\317\202
```

how can I decode it (human readable) using php ?

Comment: Check [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) for: `base_convert()` [those are octal, so 8 to 10], `intval()`, and `chr()`. Read the string one char at a time, if the char is a backslash, grab the next 3 chars and convert it. You'll wind up with the UTF8 string `Επιβεβαίωση Παραγγελίας` or "Order Confirmation" in Greek.

Comment: I tried to convert 316 but it does not work  $one=base_convert("316", 8, 10); $two=chr($one); echo $two;

Comment: All the glyphs in that string are two-byte UTF8 sequences. You will need to convert and output `\316\225` to get `Ε` [which is not a normal `E` but a Greek glyph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP: Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> A string is series of characters…
> …
> If the string is enclosed in
> double-quotes (`"`), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences
> for special characters:
>
> **Escaped characters**
>
> ```
> Sequence    Meaning
> …
> \[0-7]{1,3} the sequence of characters matching the regular expression
>             is a character in octal notation, which silently overflows
>             to fit in a byte (e.g. "\400" === "\000")
> …
> ```
>
> **Note:** Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
> occur in single quoted strings.

The following code snippet shows examples for both *double-* and *single-* quoted strings. The latter is converted using [`preg_replace_callback` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) (*Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback*):

```
<?php
// octal literal (in double quotes)
$double_quoted_string = "\316\225\317\200\316\271\316\262\316\265\316\262\316\261\316\257\317\211\317\203\316\267 \316\240\316\261\317\201\316\261\316\263\316\263\316\265\316\273\316\257\316\261\317\202";
echo $double_quoted_string . PHP_EOL;

// octal literal like string (in sigle quotes)
$single_quoted_string = '\316\225\317\200\316\271\316\262\316\265\316\262\316\261\316\257\317\211\317\203\316\267 \316\240\316\261\317\201\316\261\316\263\316\263\316\265\316\273\316\257\316\261\317\202';
echo $single_quoted_string . PHP_EOL;

function tochrs($matches) {
    return chr(intval(ltrim($matches[0], '\\'), 8));
};
$regex = "/\\\\[0-7]{3}/";
echo preg_replace_callback($regex, "tochrs", $single_quoted_string) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output**: `72104296.php`

```
Επιβεβαίωση Παραγγελίας
\316\225\317\200\316\271\316\262\316\265\316\262\316\261\316\257\317\211\317\203\316\267 \316\240\316\261\317\201\316\261\316\263\316\263\316\265\316\273\316\257\316\261\317\202
Επιβεβαίωση Παραγγελίας
```